# Como puedo sacar la diferencia de horas entre dos fechas pero con la diferencia que una se guarda con la fecha actual?

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero sacar la diferencia de horas de una fecha ingresada y la otra se guarda automáticamente con la fecha actual y me aparece este

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function diff() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Fecha\guardar.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Fecha\guardar.php on line 9
```

este es mi codigo del index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="guardar.php" method="POST">
<center>
<input type="date" name="fin">
<input type="time" name="tim"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="aceptar" value="Guardar">
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

y este es el codigo de guardar

```
<?php
include "conexion/db.php";

$code= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$fecha2= $_POST['fin'];
$tim = $_POST['tim'];
$tol = $fecha2." ".$tim;

$din = $code->diff($tol);
$horas =$din->format('%H.%i');

echo $din;
$query="insert into fecha( Fecha, FFin, Diferencia) values('$code','$tol', '$horas')"; 
$resul= $cone->query($query);

if($resul){
    echo "Datos guardados correctamente";
    header('Location: http://'.$server.'/Fecha/index.php');
}else{
    echo"No fue posible guardar los datos";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sustituye:

```
$din = $code->diff($tol);
$horas =$din->format('%H.%i');
```

Por:

```
$horas=date('H:i',strtotime($code)-strtotime($tol));
```

Y obtendrás lo que estás buscando

Comment: Funcionando! gracias amigo